# Capturing variables with Regular Expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I have been trying to capture specified variables in a program which will also evaluate the validity of simple mathematical expression.

Assuming the variable declared are a and bc.

I came up with something like this

```
^[+-][(a)(bc)]+[(a)(bc)]*+([+-x/][(a)(bc)]+[(a)(bc)]*)*$
```

My intention is to validate expressions like

```
+a-bc-a
-bc+a-a
```

But it seems this expression also returns true for

```
-b+a+ab
```

That I do not want as b is not specified as a variable. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: i think you mean `(?:(a)(bc))` not `[(a)(bc)]`

Comment: You cannot use grouping constructs inside of a character class. Also if you are validating there is no reason to use capturing groups.

Comment: This site is tremendously helpful when debugging/learning regexes. Not a paid endorsement. https://www.regex101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[+-](?:(a)|(bc))+(?:(a)|(bc))*+(?:[+-x\/](?:(a)|(bc))+(?:(a)|(bc))*)*$
```

`[]` is a character class and matches a single character, not alternation. Also your regex suffers from catastrophic backtracking. [See demo.](https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/18)

You can also reduce it to

```
^[+-](?:a|bc)+(?:[+-x\/](?:a|bc)+)*$
```

[See demo.](https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/21)

Comment: Since OP is validating, it seems that `^[+-](?:a|bc)+([+-x/](?:a|bc)+)*$` would suffice.